# git log --oneline: separator for lines of body

Tags: git, git-log

I often use

```
git log --graph  --all --oneline
```

My problem is that, if the commit message contains several lines, then they are concatenated with a space as separator.
Is it possible to define a different separator, e.g. '$'?

Comment: I would assume this is something you need to configure in your terminal?

Comment: If you follow standard git conventions (the first line of your commit should be less than 50 characters and separated from the body of the rest of your message by a blank line), you won't have this problem (see e.g. https://git-scm.com/book/uz/v2/Distributed-Git-Contributing-to-a-Project).

Comment: You could build your own format with [`git log --format="..."`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---formatltformatgt), the part between the `"` being a format string according to [the docs](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats)

Comment: You can do that with `--pretty=` and a custom format like @Torge suggested, not with `--oneline` which is a fixed format.

Comment: I looked around --pretty and -- format, but didn't find the solution. "%b" puts the body as one line (lines separated by a space) and %B puts the whole block as is (separated by NewLines).